# Unable to load the requested file: helpers/langauge_helper.php

Tags: codeigniter, ci-merchant

I am using CI Merchant and have copied all the files needed into the correct folders and added the code to do a test purchase. When I load the controller I get this message:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/langauge_helper.php

How can I get codeigniter to give me more information on why its giving this message? What would cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading helper file in constructor works too like this

```
$this->load->helper('custom'); //custom_helper.php
```

[Reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

You might be loading helper in a wrong way

Answer (score 1):

It works as below mentioned in  CodeIgniter 2.X:-

If helper file inside helpers folder named as language_helper.php
Then you can load it in controller anywhere (not only in constructor) by using

```
$this->load->helper('language');
```

Make sure your helper class naming convention is correct it must end with _helper.php

Answer (score 0):

i was loading the helper in the construct of the controller and moved it into autoload and that fixed it. No idea why it didnt work in the construct.

Comment: You probably needed to load the language helper before you loaded CI-Merchant, which would explain why it was throwing an error.